# Command-line tool to obtain OUI vendor info from MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

I have found some tools that seems to update the **OUI MAC address vendor database** on my system, like [get-oui](http://linux.die.net/man/1/get-oui), [airodump-ng-oui-update](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/update-oui.8.html) or `update-oui` :

```
update-oui(8)                          OUI                         update-oui(8)

NAME
       update-oui - download new version of the OUI and IAB lists

SYNOPSIS
       update-oui

DESCRIPTION
       update-oui  fetches  the  current  version  of the OUI and IAB lists from
       http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/index.shtml and installs it, if the
       installed versions is older than 5 days.

       This utility requires curl, wget or libwww-perl to be installed.

OPTIONS
       -q     Be quiet. Do not output messages.

       -f     Force the update, even if the file is newer than 5 days.

FILES
       /usr/share/misc/
              Directory holding symbolic links to oui.txt and iab.txt
```

But if I search for IPs on my network:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:~$ sudo netdiscover -i eth1

 92 Captured ARP Req/Rep packets, from 12 hosts.   Total size: 5520
 _____________________________________________________________________________
   IP            At MAC Address      Count  Len   MAC Vendor
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 192.168.4.31    bc:f1:f2:12:b4:93    60    3600   Unknown vendor
 192.168.4.24    f0:db:e2:de:11:80    02    120   Unknown vendor
 192.168.4.242   00:1d:7e:9c:6e:fc    05    300   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
 192.168.4.243   00:1c:10:64:63:ac    05    300   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
 192.168.4.244   00:1c:10:64:5f:94    05    300   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
 192.168.4.1     d8:61:94:e5:0b:1d    05    300   Unknown vendor
 192.168.4.246   00:1a:70:2f:ab:4b    04    240   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
 192.168.4.10    84:11:9e:2b:1c:d6    01    060   Unknown vendor
 192.168.4.11    ec:1f:72:5d:42:d0    02    120   Unknown vendor
 192.168.4.245   00:1a:70:2f:aa:63    01    060   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
 192.168.4.248   00:1a:70:2f:aa:d1    01    060   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
 192.168.4.251   44:d9:e7:0a:0b:98    01    060   Unknown vendor
```

As long as there are some MACs reported as `Unknown vendor`, I would like to search on any OUI database for its info.

What is the proper **command-line** way to perform this **search**?
Maybe something like:

```
oui-info 44:d9:e7
```

Note: I know that using the web browser I can google for the MAC's first 3 pairs, but I would like some command-line method, so I could script it or use via remote login (SSH).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not think there is an automated tool to do what you ask, but can be done by working directly on files oui.txt.

First of all it identifies the file downloaded, for example:

```
root@kalilloX:~# locate oui.txt
/var/lib/ieee-data/oui.txt
```

then search for the string you are interested. You must remove `:` or instead insert a `-`:

```
root@kalilloX:~# grep -i "44d9e7" /var/lib/ieee-data/oui.txt
44D9E7     (base 16)        Ubiquiti Networks, Inc.
```

Comment: And indirect method, but completely functional, and probably valid on any *nix, even some embedded devices. Thanks you.

Comment: For ease of use, you can define a function in your `.bashrc` as follows: 
`oui() { grep -i "$1" /var/lib/ieee-data/oui.txt; }` and use it like this `oui 44D9E7`

Answer (score 10):

A similar answer to the one of LilloX, but **using nMap** (if installed in the system):

```
luis@balanceador:~$ locate nmap-mac-prefixes
/usr/share/nmap/nmap-mac-prefixes
luis@balanceador:~$ grep 0024A5 -i /usr/share/nmap/nmap-mac-prefixes
0024A5 Buffalo
```

Supposedly working with any other program that stores OUI info, like `airodump-ng-oui-update` (to `oui.txt` file in this case), or several others:

- `/usr/share/btscanner/oui.txt`
- `/usr/share/bluelog/oui.txt`
- `/usr/share/ieee-data/oui.txt`
- `/usr/share/golismero/thirdparty_libs/netaddr/eui/oui.txt`
- `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/packetfu-1.1.11/examples/oui.txt`
- `/etc/unicornscan/oui.txt`
- `/var/lib/ieee-data/oui.txt`

Answer (score 5):

### Cross-Distro Fully Automated Solution:

The following script automates the process and works across all Linux distros because it has no dependencies on specialized packages. It simply parses the output of the `ip` command, isolates the vendor part of mac address into a variable which is finally ***grep***'ed through an online DB of vendor prefixes.

```
#!/bin/bash

OUI=$(ip addr list|grep -w 'link'|awk '{print $2}'|grep -P '^(?!00:00:00)'| grep -P '^(?!fe80)' | tr -d ':' | head -c 6)

curl -sS "http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt" | grep -i "$OUI" | cut -d')' -f2 | tr -d '\t'
```

With a bit of creativity you could adapt this to execute remotely via ssh.  I've seen other suggestions to identify vendor details using `dmidecode` for OS fingerprinting, but experienced inconsistent results with that tool when testing.  On Raspberry Pi `dmidecode` fails totally. HTH-

Comment: This is the best answer in my humble opinion, because it gives an answer without the need of (nearly) installed tools, and, as long as IEEE.Org keeps updated (it should), it must be the best database to access. The only downside is the need for internet; not a big issue nowadays.

Comment: There were a lot of OUI online databases run by private individuals/orgs.  But I chose the ieee.org one because there was less risk of it disappearing or the link changing. Glad I could help you out-

Comment: Even more, the database at IEEE.Org contains the manufacturer for “D45D64” (= ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.) whereas the file /usr/share/arp-scan/ieee-oui.txt on my Arch Linux is outdated by more than 18 month.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the actual vendor by making a request using something like CURL to this API:

```
curl -XGET "https://api.macaddress.io/v1?apiKey=at_2d31hlNQAO1PXZVTecL6yoVAxI8IW&output=vendor&search=bc:f1:f2:12:b4:93"
```

OR

```
wget -qO- "https://api.macaddress.io/v1?apiKey=at_2d31hlNQAO1PXZVTecL6yoVAxI8IW&output=vendor&search=bc:f1:f2:12:b4:93"
```

For the unknown MAC addresses listed, it returned the following results:

```
bc:f1:f2:12:b4:93 -> Cisco Systems, Inc
f0:db:e2:de:11:80 -> Apple, Inc
d8:61:94:e5:0b:1d -> Objetivos y Sevicios de Valor Añadido
84:11:9e:2b:1c:d6 -> Samsung Electronics Co, Ltd
ec:1f:72:5d:42:d0 -> Samsung Electro-Mechanics(Thailand)
44:d9:e7:0a:0b:98 -> Ubiquiti Networks Inc
```

To use the service, you need to obtain an apiKey which is free if you're under 1000 requests a day.

Comment: A practical method, indeed. This seems to be a site that offers MAC identification services (see the pricing for high number of requests at https://macaddress.io/pricing ), and, as for today (October 2018), API requests like the described in this answer appears to be free. Thanks you, Dmitri S.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script for updating oui and iab-files. Main-problem is, that the form of nmap-files is not the same as for btscan or arpwatch etc., they often have different forms (MAC-Address with double-points, with hyphens, without delimiters, upper cases, lower cases etc.

You could try this script, it is stored at https://github.com/burningfog/refresh_oui.

Please read the readme-file and if there are any questions give me a hint per mail please.
If there are other tools than named in github, please give me the path for the oui-file and some lines from this file so I can take a look on that form.

Greetings
Burning Fog

Answer (score 0):

This script builds a list of all non-loopback interfaces then displays the interface:manufacturer key-value. It consults the OUI file distributed by Wireshark.

source: https://github.com/epacua/mac-address-lookup/blob/master/mac-address.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=' '
FILE="/tmp/oui.txt"
SOURCE="https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/raw/master/manuf"

if [[ ! -f "${FILE}" ]]; then
  echo "$FILE not found. Downloading it from ${SOURCE}"
  wget -qO "$FILE" https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/raw/master/manuf
else
  echo -e "\nFile $FILE found\n"
fi

declare -A INTF_HASH
OUI=$(ip link | sed -n '1,2d;N;s/\n//;s/^[2-9]: \(\w\+\):.\+\([[:xdigit:]:]\{17\}\).\+/\1 \2/p')

while read; do
    INTERFACE=$(cut -d' ' -f1 <(echo $REPLY)) && MAC=$(cut -d' ' -f2 <(echo $REPLY) | tr 'a-f' 'A-F')
    MANUFACTURER=$(grep "${MAC:0:8}" $FILE | cut -d'    ' -f3)
    echo "INTERFACE: ${INTERFACE} -- ${MAC} -- $MANUFACTURER"
    INTF_HASH+=( [$(echo "$INTERFACE")]=$(echo "$MAC") )
done < <(echo $OUI)

IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat `locate nmap-mac-prefixes` | grep -i ^YOUR_OID_START
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash

arp -an | egrep -v incomplete | while read line ; do mac=$( echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $4}' | sed 's/:/-/g' | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" | cut -c 1-8 ) ; vendor=$( egrep "$mac" /usr/share/hwdata/oui.txt ) ; echo "$line : $vendor" ; done
```

Output:

```
? (192.168.88.36) at 60:03:08:a8:4e:86 [ether]  on eth0 : 60-03-08   (hex)              Apple, Inc.
? (192.168.88.38) at d8:8f:76:6f:59:0a [ether]  on eth0 : D8-8F-76   (hex)              Apple, Inc.
```